# photoswipe gallery – X-icon between last and first image

Tags: jquery, gallery, photoswipe

photoswipe 3.0.5, jquery 1.8.2
gallery works fine.
Only there is a black scrren with the X icon between the last and the first image of the carousel, appending class = ps-carousel-item-0 ps-carousel-item-error
I used example 02-jquery.
The js photoswipe call:
    (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var options = {};
                    $(".gallery a").photoSwipe(options);
                });
            }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

See here: http://www.ditib-ma.de/bilder-und-panoramen/bilder/gebetssaal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you double check your file names in "gallery a"? This is most likely because it can't find the file but there is a file listed there.

Comment: thx! found it! There was a hidden element somewhere else also with class="gallery"...